# Can a domain and a subdomain use the same database?

Tags: android, wordpress, mobile, woocommerce, buddypress

I have a good reason for asking this question. I'm building a WordPress project that involves woocommerce and buddypress but I cannot seem to find a reliable platform that would support both woocommerce and buddypress very well to bundle the mobile application and submit them to app stores. I have checked appresser but it is very expensive for me (I wish there was monthly payment but there is not).

So I want to split the components, by keeping the woocommerce and the wordpress section in the main domain say: example.com and host the buddypress section in a subdomain say: community.example.com. This way I can easily see a cheaper alternative to create the woocommerce shop mobile application and another mobile app platform that supports only buddypress. But I want the registration to be done once via the main wordpress section, since the wordpress user roles would be synched with the buddypress member types to regulate the previleges in the buddypress site.

Please is it possible to use the same database for both version of the sites and keep them synched viz: the wordpress user roles and the buddypress member types?

Or if there is a better alternative that is quite affordable that I can use other than appresser.

I should be able to create the woocommerce shop mobile app using react native or phone gap and the buddypress mobile app using a specialized buddypress platform. But is it possible is what I really want to know.

Answer (score 0):

Apppresser recently switched to monthly payments. Check their prices here https://apppresser.com/pricing/

It's possible to do what you want by using WordPress Multisite in a subdomain mode. Install both Woocommerce and BuddyPress, but WC shout be activated on main site, while BuddyPress - on a community subdomain. They will both use the same database for users.

Comment: https://appresser.com is billed annually I could not find the monthly billing. During purchase you are billed annually and on renewal it is the same.

Comment: Oh, I see: "$19/mo. Billed Annually". My bad, didn't pay attention to small letters :(. Everything else is still valid though.

Comment: There's worona.org, and I remember seeing one more open source solution

Comment: Using multi site would complicate an already complicated solution, and I would have to look for a mobile platform that supports multisite. I have used it before on a project I think I have enough to worry about viz woocommerce and buddypress.    

Other than multisite solution, is there any other way this can be done?

Comment: I'm thinking of using a new database for the subdomain and verify if they have an account with the main site if so, their account details would be updated. The only reason the connection is because it is a membership site and I want the user role of paid members to be synched with a certain buddypress member type and the same for free member to another. 

So if there is another way, I'm most happy.

worona.org does not support woocommerce. Thanks anyway!